# In R, is there a difference between the following code? df$age[df$age > 20] df[df$age>20, ]$age

Tags: r

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv")

df$age[df$age > 20]

df[df$age>20, ]$age
```

I checked that they return the same output. Is there a difference between the two other than syntax?

Comment: No...they both are the same.

Comment: Offhand I would guess that the first one was faster in large data situations, but probably not by a noticeable amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the methods is the same but computation time is different. It could be recommender to use: `trees$Height[trees$Height > 80]`

```
bench::mark(trees$Height[trees$Height > 80]
, trees[trees$Height > 80, "Height"]
, trees[trees$Height > 80,]$Height)
#  expression                              min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
#  <bch:expr>                         <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
#1 trees$Height[trees$Height > 80]      2.31µs   2.73µs   321092.        0B
#2 trees[trees$Height > 80, "Height"]  15.69µs  17.24µs    56991.        0B
#3 trees[trees$Height > 80, ]$Height   48.38µs   52.3µs    18666.        0B
```

Answer (score 0):

The result is the same. It's just that you subset for the column `age` first in example 1, but do it at the end in example 2.

To understand why, try just:

```
df$age > 20
```

It will give you a vector of TRUE and FALSE values.

So in the first example:

```
df$age[df$age > 20]
```

we have "return values from the column (vector) `age` where the comparison is TRUE".

In the second example:

```
df[df$age>20, ]$age
```

we have "find rows in the data frame `df` where the comparison is TRUE, and then return just the `age` column (vector)".

You could also write the second example as:

```
df[df$age>20, "age"]
```

Comment: If it answers your question please accept the answer.